# JSF User Define Table required multiple Data Storage

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am able to print the data from a JSF home page in form of table. But the issue is that it is able to print only one entry at a time.What if I enter more names i.e. name and password without using Database. Please find managed bean and format of table is taken by tutorial.

```
 @SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "pprBean")
public class Demos {

    static String firstname ;
    static String password;


    private static final ArrayList<Demos> employees
    = new ArrayList<Demos>(Arrays.asList(
            new Demos()
    )); 

    public ArrayList<Demos> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }



    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


}



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view>
<h:body>
<h:form>  

    <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5">  
        <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name:" style="font-weight:bold"/>  

        <p:inputText id="name" value="#{pprBean.firstname}" /> 

        <h:outputLabel for="pass" value="Pass:" style="font-weight:bold"/>  
         <p:inputText id="pass" value="#{pprBean.password}" />   

        <p:commandButton value="Submit"/>  
    </h:panelGrid>
  <p:outputLabel value="Result"></p:outputLabel>
    <h:dataTable value="#{pprBean.employees}" var="result" cellspacing="2"
         styleClass="employeeTable"
         headerClass="employeeTableHeader"
         rowClasses="employeeTableOddRow,employeeTableEvenRow" border="3">
         <h:column>                 
            <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>                   
            #{result.firstname}
         </h:column>
          <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Password</f:facet>
            #{result.password}
         </h:column>
         </h:dataTable>

</h:form> 
</h:body>
</f:view>

</html>
```

Comment: You can get a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16762538/354831) this is pretty much the same as you are trying to do.

Comment: But what i will have to do in my code for getting expected result           Thanks in Advance