# Dynamic text fields in JSF

Tags: jsf-2

I have the exact same question as asked in this topic: [Dynamic adding text fields in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761441/dynamic-adding-text-fields-in-jsf)

To delete a text field, I used as it was said in the anwser:

```
<f:ajax listener="#{bean.onButtonRemoveFieldClick(field)}" immediate="true" render="@form" />
```

My problem is in the `render="@form"`. I have a really long form, so it takes quite a while to be refreshed. And `render="myHDataTable"` does not work. Have you a solution for this?

Comment: When using id, don't put `@` in front of it.

Comment: I did not use it, I edited my question.

Comment: You forgot to tell the actual problem. "Does not work" is really unhelpful in understanding the cause and therefore also in providing the solution. Elaborate about the problem as if you're the developer, not as if you're the enduser.

Comment: What I meant is that my obejct is deleted from my list in my Java Bean, but the result is not rendered on the screen.

Comment: then check the id in your render attribute

Comment: The id is correct. I saw in all the forums, they put a `render="@form"` for the delete action, and a `render="tableId"` to add a field. There gotta be a reason for this...